# CodecConfigurationException with enums

Tags: java, mongodb, groovy, mongo-java-driver

I am attempting to create an example that demonstrates enum support in mongodb java driver POJOs. The example fails with the exception `CodecConfigurationException: Cannot find a public constructor for 'PType6_'`

The used version of mongodb java driver is 3.11

`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    /*other dependencies*/
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:3.11.0'
    /*other dependencies*/
}
```

**The Enum Type** `PType6_`

```
public enum PType6_ {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE;

    public static PType6_ random() {
        return PType6_.values()[getRandomNumber(PType6_.values().length)];
    }
```

**A POJO Holding The Enum Type** `PType7_`

```
public class PType7_ {
    private int number;
    private PType6_ pType6_1;

    public PType7_ setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
        return this;
    }

    public PType7_ setPType6_1(PType6_ pType6_1) {
        this.pType6_1 = pType6_1;
        return this;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public PType6_ getPType6_1() {
        return pType6_1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PType7_{number=" + number + ", pType6_1=" + pType6_1 + '}';
    }

    public static PType7_ random() {
        return new PType7_()
                .setNumber(getRandomNumber(1000))
                .setPType6_1(PType6_.random());
    }
}
```

**A CodecRegistryFactory** `CustomCodecRegistriesFactoryWithPOJOs`

```
public class CustomCodecRegistriesFactoryWithPOJOs {
    public static CodecRegistry getDefault() {
        return MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry();
    }

    public static CodecRegistry getDefaultWithPOJOs(final Class<?>... pojoClasses) {
        return CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().register(pojoClasses).build()),
                getDefault()
        );
    }

    public static CodecRegistry getDefaultWithPOJOsAndConventions(final List<Convention> conventions, final Class<?>... pojoClasses) {
        return CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                CodecRegistries.fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().conventions(conventions).register(pojoClasses).build()),
                getDefault()
        );
    }
}
```

**The Test Methods**

```
    @Test
    public void demonstrate_POJO_default_enum_registeringEnumClass_throwsException() {
        final MongoClient mc = buildMongoClientWithCustomCodec(CustomCodecRegistriesFactoryWithPOJOs.getDefaultWithPOJOs(PType7_.class, PType6_.class));
        final MongoDatabase mdb = initRandomDatabase(mc);
        final String colName = "col";
        mdb.createCollection(colName);
        final MongoCollection<Document> colDocs = mdb.getCollection(colName);
        final MongoCollection<PType7_> colTyped = mdb.getCollection(colName, PType7_.class);

        printTitle("[Encoding] Inserting PType7_ POJO Object");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            colTyped.insertOne(PType7_.random());
        }

        printTitle("Reading Collection Raw");
        printDocumentMongoCollection(colDocs);

        printTitle("[Decoding] Reading PType7_ POJO Objects As Strings");
        try {
            for (final PType7_ item : colTyped.find()) {
                out.println(item);
            }
        } catch (final CodecConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(out);
        }
    }
```

The error is thrown when an attempt is made to decode the enum `PType6_`

**Summary**
I want a full and working example that demonstrates utilizing mongodb java driver POJO support for enums.

**Reference** : [POJOs - Plain Old Java Objects | Enum support](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/bson/pojos/#enum-support)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this exception is thrown when the enum type class `PType6_` itself is registered as a POJO. This somehow disables the default behavior which prevents the enum from being serialized.

The following test method works

```
    @Test
    public void demonstrate_POJO_default_enum() {
        final MongoClient mc = buildMongoClientWithCustomCodec(CustomCodecRegistriesFactoryWithPOJOs.getDefaultWithPOJOs(PType7_.class));
        final MongoDatabase mdb = initRandomDatabase(mc);
        final String colName = "col";
        mdb.createCollection(colName);
        final MongoCollection<Document> colDocs = mdb.getCollection(colName);
        final MongoCollection<PType7_> colTyped = mdb.getCollection(colName, PType7_.class);

        printTitle("[Encoding] Inserting PType7_ POJO Object");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            colTyped.insertOne(PType7_.random());
        }

        printTitle("Reading Collection Raw");
        printDocumentMongoCollection(colDocs);

        printTitle("[Decoding] Reading PType7_ POJO Objects As Strings");
        for (final PType7_ item : colTyped.find()) {
            out.println(item);
        }
    }
```

The only difference is that the working test method did **not** provide the enum class as a POJO.

This doesn't work

```
    final MongoClient mc = buildMongoClientWithCustomCodec(CustomCodecRegistriesFactoryWithPOJOs.getDefaultWithPOJOs(PType7_.class, PType6_.class));
```

This works

```
    final MongoClient mc = buildMongoClientWithCustomCodec(CustomCodecRegistriesFactoryWithPOJOs.getDefaultWithPOJOs(PType7_.class));
```

**Conclusion** enums are handled as properties by default and they are not needed to be added as POJO classes. Adding them as POJO classes disables the default behavior for the added enum class.